# Next js changes query params in url

Tags: next.js

I want to add data in url params after clicking on a button in next.js

```js
  function send() {
    router.push(
      { pathname: "/", query: { n: "firstparam,secondparam" } },
      undefined,
      {
        shallow: true
      }
    );
  }
```

After clicnking, i get in the url:

```css
site/?n=firstparam%2Csecondparam
```

So, nextjs instead of the `,`, adds `%2C`. How to avoid all these signs and to get a valid url without using `replace()?`like:`site/?n=firstparam,secondparam`
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sinoussi-d9z77?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 2):

`%2C` is the url encoding of `,`, what Next.js does is the proper thing to do, since `,` is not a valid character.

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent(','))
```

You can try to pass the url as string.

```js
function send() {
  router.push('/?n=firstparam,secondparam', undefined, {
    shallow: true,
  });
}
```